# Object & Collection Initializers and Accessors

Tags: c#, accessor, object-initializers, collection-initializer

I'd like to start off with that I'm new to C# so accessors and Object Initializers are a completely new concept to me. That said, I think I have an okay handle on them except the following example is really confusing me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

class How {
    public ObservableCollection<int> Coll {
        get { return coll_; }
        set {
            Console.WriteLine("Setter for Coll Called!");
            coll_.Clear();
            foreach (int i in value)
                coll_.Add(i);
        }
    }

    public string Field {
        get { return field_; }
        set {
            Console.WriteLine("Setter for field called");
            field_ = value;
        }
    }

    // To confirm the internal coll_ is actually set
    public void Test() {
        foreach(int i in coll_)
            Console.Write(i + " ");
    }

    public How() {
        coll_ = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        field_ = "";
    }

    private ObservableCollection<int> coll_;
    private string field_;
}

public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
        var how = new How {
            Coll = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
            Field = "Test Field",
        };

        Console.Write("Coll: ");
        foreach (int i in how.Coll)
            Console.Write(i + " ");
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Field: " + how.Field);


        Console.Write("Internal coll_: ");
        how.Test();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

The output of the above code is (see live example [here](http://ideone.com/rcYE1Y)):

```
Setter for field called
Coll: 1 2 3 4 5 
Field: Test Field
Internal coll_: 1 2 3 4 5
```

`Field` operates exactly as I'd expect it to, but `Coll` confuses me. The setter to `Coll` is never called, which to me implies that Collection Initializers don't mix will with Properties (or at least non Auto-Properties). However, if that's the case, I would have expected a compile-time error.

Regardless of that part of the behavior, what confuses me even further is that the internal value of `coll_` is somehow set to the initializer value.

I'm interested in knowing a) why `Coll`'s set is not called, and also how C# is able to set the value of `coll_`. Is the use of that identifier in the get and set accessors for `Coll` enough for C# to identify `coll_` as the internal storage; or maybe since it's set because it's the only member of the corresponding type?

Comment: This line calls the Coll setter _Coll = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },_

Comment: @Steve I also thought so but it doesn't. Hold on, updating the question with a live example.

Comment: @Steve Added [this](http://ideone.com/rcYE1Y) live example to the question.

Comment: Collection initializers are translated into `Add` calls. Normally you'd see `new List <int> { 1, 2, 3 }` in examples, but that consists of two parts: the `new` part and the collection initializer. Here, you only have the collection initializer - the `new`ing has already been done in `How`'s constructor. You should be seeing call(s?) to `Coll`'s getter instead.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet I had no idea it translated to repeated Add calls! That makes so much sense. Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: @definecindyconst, I saw your issue is resolved in a comment but I still posted an answer just in case because 1. it is good then Question has a clear Answer 2. I like collection initializers and I had some details to add :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var how = new How 
          {
              Coll = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
              Field = "Test Field",
          };
```

this is a object initialization syntax for `How` class.

`Coll = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` is a form of collection-itializer syntax meant for collection properties which don't have public setter (but works equally well with those which *have* setter). This form requieres for `Coll` to be instantiated (be not `null`): try to comment `coll_ = new ObservableCollection<int>();` line in constructor and the program will crash with NullReferenceException.

`Coll = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` is translated in repeated `Coll.Add` calls:

```
Coll.Add(1);
Coll.Add(2);
Coll.Add(3);
Coll.Add(4);
Coll.Add(5);
```

to confirm it add event handler in `How` constructor:

```
public How() 
{
    coll_ = new ObservableCollection<int>();

    coll_.CollectionChanged += (o,e) => 
    { Console.WriteLine("New items: {0}", String.Join (",", e.NewItems.OfType<int>())); };

    field_ = "";
}
```

Collection initializers are described in §7.6.10.3 of C# Language Specification